# passport, mongo, express, shopping cart tutorial lags on click submit after a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I use  passport authentication, after submit,  and passing all validations, on successRedirect, the application does not redirect to the specified route and instead just loads and after a while it crashes.  I am following this youtube tutorial by Max S. and here, I will load my `passport.js` my `index.js` and my `app.js` that has express imports.

HERES PASSSPORT.JS

```js
var passport = require("passport");
var User = require("../models/user");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy; //chaining the object `Strategy`

//this function tells passport how to store the user in the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id); //whenever you want to store user in your session, serialize it by id (hence `user.id`)
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  //use mongo method to find by id
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user); //when using `done`, return err (first) if unsuccessful or the user if successful
  });
});

//----- were not creating a new user yet...

//below we create a new user with a local strategy
//`use` is a passport method that takes the first string argument as the name of the local strategy (below: `local-signup`), and new LocalStrategy takes two argument 1. an object configuration and 2. a call back function
passport.use(
  "local-signup",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      //object configuration
      usernameField: "email", //tell passport that usernameField is email
      passwordField: "password", //tell passport that passwordField is password
      passReqToCallback: true //which means that in the callback function below you can access and use the (request, email, password and done)
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      //the call back function
      //check for validations here, before running the query to database.
      req
        .checkBody("email", "invalid email")
        .notEmpty()
        .isEmail();
      req
        .checkBody("password", "invalid password")
        .notEmpty()
        .isLength({
          min: 4
        });
      var errors = req.validationErrors();
      console.log("req.validationErrors() 44 >>>> ", errors);
      if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(errors) {
          messages.push(errors.value + "" + errors.msg);
          console.log("messages here >>>>> ", messages)
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash("error", messages));
      }
        //use mongo method to find one (which is email)
        User.findOne({
          'email': email,
          function(err, user) {
            //equal to the second argument passed in the call back function
            if (err) {
              //check1
              console.log("ERROR HERE passport 59 >>>>>>");
              return done(err);
            }
            if (user) {
              console.log("USER HERE >>>>>>>");
              //in the next line of code:
              //null -> means no error but also
              //false -> means the process is unsuccessful
              //message -> tells user email is already taken
              return done(null, false, {
                messages: "Email is already in use!"
              }); //check2
            }
            //after passing both checks above, we can create a NEW USER
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.email = email;
            newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password); //in user.js (under model folder, we implement bcrypt-nodejs hashing capability)
            newUser.save(function(err, result) {
              //we will save the newUser
              if (err) {
                //check1
                return done(err);
              } else {
                return done(null, newUser);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      
    }
  )
);
```

HERES INDEX.JS (my routes)

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var csrf = require('csurf'); //import protection to hashed password
var csrfProtection = csrf(); //initiate it here like a middleware
router.use(csrfProtection);
var passport = require('passport');
// var passport = require("../config/passport");

var Product = require("../models/product");
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //were referencing model here and using `find()` method to query the database
  Product.find(function(err, prod){
   if (err) {
     //check1
     return done(err);
   }
    var productChunks = []; //were gonna render this array below, in our HOOK, as a key in our hbs page
    var chunksPerRow = 3;//just to say, we want each row to contain three cards/container
    //here we loop through prod
    for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i += chunksPerRow) {// i is incremented by three
      productChunks.push(prod.slice(i, i + chunksPerRow)) // logic for keeping each row at three chunks
    }
    res.render("shop/index", {
      title: "Shopping Cart",//hook
      products: productChunks//hook
    });
  });
});
//create our signup route (get)
router.get('/user/signup', function(req, res, next){
  //using flash messages after validation is complete
  var throwMessage = req.flash('error');
  res.render('user/signup', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: throwMessage, hasErrors: throwMessage.length>0}) // this is being handled by the csurf package
})
//passport doesnt know the authenticate method because its not imported in this file
//you can import passport here, OR you can require config/passport in the app.js
router.post('/user/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/user/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/user/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}))

router.get('/user/profile', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('user/profile');
})
module.exports = router;
```

HERE I HAVE MY APP.JS

```js
// import { extname } from 'path';

var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session')//to use csurf you need session installed
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var validator = require('express-validator');



//route
var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");

var app = express();

//mongoose connect method
//expects an input, which is the path of the server, you can check it after you ran mongod
//the `/shopping` is the name of the database you intend to create
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping");
//require helper -> config/passport here after mongoose connect
require('./config/passport')

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'})) //extname helps identify the name of the files in view folder as `.hbs`
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');//this refers to the engine above '.hbs'

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
// parse urlencoded request bodies into req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret:'mysecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));//session initialized
//resave = true, session will be saved on a server on each request no matter it saved or not - depracated
//saveUninitialized = true, the essions will be saved even if its not intialized - depracated

//add flash  and passport after  session secret is initialized ORDER MATTERS
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
// app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

HERE MY PACKAGE JSON

```js
{
  "name": "shopping-cart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "csurf": "^1.9.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.0.3",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "session": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!  [heres the tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHNLWHGCBEc&lc=z13edvx4wqfuxlft122jzpzivrfwz5nbi04.1522433628800274) I would love to complete this tutorial but Im stuck with on signup click submit, it doesnt redirect (even after passing validations).  THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error ис in passport.js lines 45, 46 you type User.findOne({ 'email': email, ..... corect is User.findOne({ 'email': email}, .... you missing bracket after email, and then check all bracket in function since line to 32 to end﻿